# Echo doesn't print what I want on the browser

Tags: php, html

Simple, I had a html that echo from php (saven in .php) but not even a simpe code as

```
    <?php echo"ggg"; ?>
```

works, I tried with xammp and Wamp either chrome and firefox but doesn't work.
What can I do?

edit: already solved, I forgot to run it from localhost, thank you all.

Comment: Are you sure that PHP is enabled? What does `phpinfo()` show?

Comment: Your above code should work fine - ensure that PHP is enabled on your server.

Comment: What does your code do? you say it does not work but the output is empty or you do see the text <?php echo"ggg"; ?> in your html?

Comment: Have you ensured that you have actually visited the correct page that is displaying the output?

Comment: My page shows this http://imgur.com/a/mzXBB

Comment: Yes, PHP is enabled, phpmyadmin works, but phpinfo() shows nothing

Comment: This is the code, nothing seems repeated http://imgur.com/a/MyiUY

Answer (score 0):

Any of these (or more) could be your answer why it is not working

1. Is there actually PHP running on your computer? Check it with `<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>`
2. Are you accesing the file through your browser doing something like `http://localhost/myfile.php`
3. If it is on a remote server, is there PHP installed?
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/43129028/2151290
4. Put your file inside `c:/xampp/htdocs` for `xampp` or `c:/wamp/www` for `wamp` 
   // Note that drive name may vary depending where you install c: or d:

Comment: I agree with the sentiment - it's bad style to omit spaces - but this doesn't answer the question. The OP's code should work, bad as it looks.